# Using a modified Vigenere cipher algorithm, decryption does not result in original input

Tags: java, encryption, vigenere

I have made a modified Vigenere cipher algorithm, however I'm running into issues. If I encrypt a `String`, then decrypt the result, I don't get my original `String` back. My source code:

```
public class ViganereEncryptionBase64 {

    private char[] keys = new char[19];

    int sizeKey = 0;
    int cimin = 0;

    final String MVEAs = " !\"#$%&'()=+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~";

    public ViganereEncryptionBase64() {
        String keys = "bangdollaMC08ITATS";
        this.keys = keys.toCharArray();
    }

    public String encrypt(String toEncrypt) {
        char charsToEncrypt[] = toEncrypt.toCharArray();
        char encryptedChars[] = toEncrypt.toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < encryptedChars.length) {

            int sube = MVEAs.indexOf(charsToEncrypt[i]) + MVEAs.indexOf(keys[sizeKey]) + cimin;

            sizeKey++;
            if (sizeKey == keys.length)
                sizeKey = 0;

            encryptedChars[i] = MVEAs.charAt(Math.floorMod(sube, 95));
            cimin = MVEAs.indexOf(encryptedChars[i]);
            i += 1;
        }
        return String.valueOf(encryptedChars);
    }

    public String decrypt(String toDecrypt) {
        char charsToDecrypt[] = toDecrypt.toCharArray();
        char decryptedChars[] = toDecrypt.toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < charsToDecrypt.length) {
            int sube = MVEAs.indexOf(charsToDecrypt[i]) - MVEAs.indexOf(keys[sizeKey]) - cimin;

            sizeKey++;
            if (sizeKey == keys.length)
                sizeKey = 0;
            decryptedChars[i] = MVEAs.charAt(Math.floorMod(sube, 95));
            cimin = MVEAs.indexOf(charsToDecrypt[i]);
            i++;
        }
        return String.valueOf(decryptedChars);
    }
}
```

A usage case that illustrates the issue is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ViganereEncryptionBase64 viganere = new ViganereEncryptionBase64();
    System.out.println("Result encryption: " + viganere.encrypt("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">"));
    viganere = new ViganereEncryptionBase64();
    System.out.println("Result description: " + viganere.decrypt("~at,4X~<Cp|\"(>rdnds~1x_\\XTmN5T{irX-9DZv+opkhJLbT[x7Mk/'J&|p&A0qAMR_yh9|H#\\Y91/kKtQI,Su3Ik, p$@IH.c:Ue'Lj25X L#[3f8ql3U]oF"));
}
```

where The original input is `"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">"`

and that encrypted result is `"~at,4X~<Cp|\"(>rdnds~1x_\\XTmN5T{irX-9DZv+opkhJLbT[x7Mk/'J&|p&A0qAMR_yh9|H#\\Y91/kKtQI,Su3Ik, p$@IH.c:Ue'Lj25X L#[3f8ql3U]oF"`

and then the decrypted result is `"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">"`

which is different.

Comment: I'm not sure I see your issue, please could you explain more clearly what your problem is?

Comment: @sebastian Troy I Have a problem when I run my application results dihasil word right by Dectiption process is not the same as the initial text of his plaint
In My Result And My Call Method U can see My Problem

Comment: can shorten your code so the only code is the problem code ? `~at,4X~<Cp|"(>rdnds~1x_\XTmN5T{irX-9DZv+opkhJLbT[x7Mk/'J&|p&A0qAMR_yh9|H#\Y91/kKtQI,Su3Ik, p$@IH.c:Ue'Lj25X L#[3f8ql3U]oF` is a bit long and confusing. Also your English is a little fractured so it is hard to pinpoint the exact problem. I get that some input does not match an output, but exactly what doesn't match is still hard to work out.

Comment: That is the point "I get that some input does not match an output" I Try I already try to replace his plaintext but still like it maybe you can help me
I apologize for my english very bad

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8xbLb3JvmSGaUdZR1AtUzJIVE0/view?usp=sharing This My Projeck

Comment: I'm not seeing a difference between your inputs and your outputs... There is a difference in `'\'` backslash characters but that is because these are being used as [escape sequences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html). Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

So your encryption and decryption are working perfectly, I have run your code and not seen any difference between any test inputs and outputs.

I think that you may be confused by [the backslashes `\` being used as escape characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) if we use an example that doesn't require escape sequences:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    viganere = new ViganereEncryptionBase64();
    System.out.println("Result encryption: " + viganere.encrypt("Hello!"));
    // Which is encrypted to "+R.b7("

    viganere = new ViganereEncryptionBase64();
    System.out.println("Result description: " + viganere.decrypt("+R.b7("));
    // Which is decrypted to "Hello!"
}
```

you can see that it works perfectly.

In your example there is a `\` before each `"`, this is so that Java doesn't think that you've ended your `String`, you'll notice that it lets you use `"` half way through a `String` without ending it.

So in reality there is still a `\` in your `String`, it looks like there isn't one because it won't get printed by `System.out.println`. This will be true of all escaped characters; when printed to the user, they will be translated into tabs or new lines e.t.c.

Comment: I want to encrypt a source code and its definitely there
punctuation such as "/ etc

Comment: Puntuation using '\' itself won't be an issue, in fact the preceding '\' were actually present in the decrypted `String` it's just `System.out.println` won't show them. I'll edit my answer to clarify.